# The number of the ring isomorphism, $\phi$ : $\mathbb{Z}_p[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ for prime number, $p$(please let me know my mistakes.)

Tags: abstract-algebra

The number of the ring isomorphism, $\phi$ :  $\mathbb{Z}_p[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ for prime number, $p$

I knew the answer is $p(p-1)$ already.

Here is my solution. Since the $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ is a P.I.D and $\mathbb{Z}_p[x] \lhd \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

So, $\exists f(x) \in  \mathbb Z_p[x]  s.t.$ $\langle f(x) \rangle = \mathbb Z_p[x]$

I don't know the exact form of the $f(x)$, But I can surely say the existence of the $f(x)$ because of the P.I.D. Considering a any unit(or constant) $c$ in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$, Then $f(x) \vert c(\in \mathbb Z_p)$. So the $deg f =0$, Hence the $f = c$ . (I.e. $\mathbb Z_p[x] = \langle c  \rangle$ for $c \in \mathbb Z_p$ ) So In this argument, If the $f(x)$ exists, the $f$ would be a unit owing to $c \in \langle f \rangle$ for $c \in \mathbb{Z_p}$

Then, owing to the $\mathbb Z_p[x] = \langle c \rangle = \langle u \rangle$ for $c,u \in \mathbb Z_p$(Here the $c$ and $u$ are units of the $\mathbb Z_p[x]$)

Only we just left is to find the $\phi : \mathbb Z_p[x] \to \mathbb Z_p[x]$ by $c \to u$

So there are $p-1$ units in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$, considering the each $c$ and $u$ respectively, so my answer is $(p-1)^2$.

Which point did I have a mistakes?

Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: analyse your proof in the case $p=2$.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's a matter of finding mistakes, it's incomprehensible. For instance you say "$\exists f(x)$ s.t." - so what, clearly we can take $f=1$ and this is so. So you can't just be saying "$f$ exists" you must mean something more. But what?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ cannot be generated by a single polynomial. You can only say that any proper ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ is generated by a single polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- every ring homomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]$ its restriction to
  $\mathbb{F}_p$ is an identity:

Let be $\varphi$ a ring homomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]$, for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\varphi(n\times 1) = n \times 1 $, so
$$\varphi\left|_{\mathbb{F}_p}\right. = id $$

- every ring homomorphism $\varphi$ of $\ \mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]$ is determinated by $\varphi(X)$
- every ring isomorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]$, $\varphi(X)$
  is polynomial of degree $1$:

$\varphi$ induce an isomorphism:
$$\bar{\varphi} : \mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]/X \to \mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]/\varphi(X) $$
but $\mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]/X \simeq \mathbb{F}_p$ so degree of $\varphi(X)$ is $1$. so $\varphi(X) = aX + b$ where $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ and $b\in\mathbb{F}_p$